# Why D3 v.7 MouseEvent transform properties are not affected on programmatical pan

Tags: d3.js, d3fc

I have two ways to pan the chart. Drag with mouse or a button (pan with fixed period).
Canvas is defined as

```
this.canvas = d3.select('#chart')
    .datum(displayData)
    .call(this.chart);
```

Chart is defined like

```
this.chart = chartCartesian(this.xScale, d3.scaleLinear())
    .webglPlotArea(this.barSeries)
    .xDomain(this.xScale.domain())
    .decorate(context =>
        context
            .call(this.zoom)
            .call(pointer)
    );
```

... and on button click this is called:

```
this.canvas.transition().call(
   this.zoom.transform,
   this.transform(direction)
);
```

...were transform function returns:

```
d3.zoomIdentity
  .translate(position, 0)
  .scale(/* current transform.k set in chart's zoomFn */);
```

... zoomFn is called and seems ok.

```
this.zoom = d3
   .zoom()
   .scaleExtent([1, this.timeFrameInS])
   .translateExtent([[0, 0], [this.webglService.canvasWidth$.value, this.webglService.canvasHeight$.value]])
   .extent([[0, 0], [this.webglService.canvasWidth$.value, this.webglService.canvasHeight$.value]])
   .on('zoom', event => {
      this.xPos = Math.trunc(event.transform.x);
      this.zoomEvent = event;
   });
```

Now If I use mouse to pan - zoomFn is called with event.transform.x set by previous MouseEvent and not the programmatical event.

Using d3fc.chartCartesian.
Tried zoom.translateTo(selection, x, y) which is reseting zoom (and pan)

Comment: Can you post the code involving that mouse event?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky I added zoomFn fragment. Chart's "on:zoom" is called with MouseEvent by mouse drag (I have no code for it).

Comment: Are you calling the zoom on this.canvas or another element?

Comment: @AndrewReid I added chart code.